# How to scan iBeacon in Background even when the Application is killed in android?

Tags: java, android

This is the first time i'am working on iBeacons scanning and i can able to scan the iBeacons when the application is running.

Now i want to scan the iBeacons even when the application is killed and get the notification when it detects any iBeacon.
Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It kind of depends on which beacon set you are using, for example Estimote. Which is the one I am using.

In Android you monitor for beacons in the background with a BroadcastReceiver, which receives a signal from your telephone when it complets its bootup sequence, so it can start ranging. See below partial code how I did it:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
        serviceIntent.setAction("com.beacon.receiver.NotificationService");
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

So when your application receives the signal that your phone is booted succesfully I will call my NotificationService class which inherits from Service, which will start monitoring and create a notification when it 'sees' one or more beacons.

Hope I helped you in the right path with this.

Comment: Hi Marvin, Thank you for your reply. i'm not trying for a particular kind of beacon set. i'm trying to detect for all kind of beacons

Comment: Hi Talapaneni, this will be difficult since most beacon vendors will provide you with their own SDK which will let you set up ranging- and monitoring listeners, among other things. More often than not they won't let you scan for beacons other than their own. I'm currently in the final phase for my thesis on this subject and have not encountered a SDK which will let you scan for all beacons of different suppliers. But good luck, beacons are very fun to work with.

Comment: Hi Marvin, Thank you very-much for your suggestion. Here i can able to scan multiple Beacons, but the problem is i con able to scan in background (i.e; when the app is killed).

Comment: Depends which mobile OS you're using. I don't know much about iOS, but Android will do this with above example. Use a BroadcastReceiver.